# Query elastic search with many levels of "bool query"

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to implement a search system with ElasticSearch.
My problem lies in the location of objects First, the searched objects can have different type of location:

- Country
- Country + State
- Country + State  + District

Here is an example:

```
Country = A
State = B
District = C

Currently I get all the objects that have the location :
Country = A and State = B and District = C

I want also find objects which have the location:
only Country = A
and
only Country = A and State = B
```

It's a bit complicated to explain but the principle is.

So I created the following query ElasticSearch :

```
"query" : {
        [{"bool":{
            "should":[
                {"bool":{
                     "must":[
                         {"match":{"country":"-223"}},
                         {"match":{"state":"-3760"}},
                         {"match":{"district":"-8245"}}
                     ]
                }},
                {"bool":{
                     "must":[
                         {"match":{"country":"-223"}},
                         {"match":{"state":"-3760"}},
                         {"match":{"district":""}}
                      ]
                }},
                {"bool":{
                     "must":[
                         {"match":{"country":"-223"}},
                         {"match":{"state":""}},
                         {"match":{"district":""}}
                      ]
                }}
            ]
        }}]
  }
```

But it does not work, I do not really know what I've done wrong.
I read the documentation on this site:

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/bool-query/

And I try all that seemed useful for my problem but without success
Is someone can help me find what's wrong?

Thank you F.

Answer (score 1):

I do this by indexing the data bit bit differently.

For every document I index multiple values in the location field for each document namely:

```
country
country/state
country/state/district
```

That way if I want to find everything in a certain country i search for location:country and if I want everything in a certain state I search for location:country/state

This has the side effect of being REALLY nice for nested faceting.